# MongoDB bulk insert using Python fails

Tags: python, mongodb

I implemented a simple batch upload with the following code, assuming I could aggregate a pre-set number of Json docs (aka ecpDocSorted which is a dict) into a bulk list and flush it e.g. after collecting 5 docs. The ecpDocSorted contains a simple Json structure - all key/values with no ids.

The code snippet looks like this

```
     #
     # Sorting the ecpDoc by keys
     #
     for k in sorted(ecpDoc.keys()):
         ecpDocSorted[k] = ecpDoc[k]
     ecpDoc    = dict(ecpDocSorted)

    #
    # Insert into MongoDB
    #
    bulk.append(ecpDocSorted)
    if len(bulk) == 5:
        # insert into Mongo
        result = mycol.insert_many(bulk)
        print(result)
        bulk = []
```

Uploading an individual doc (using len(bulk)==1) works fine and the document ends up in Mongo.

For any other number (e.g. len(bulk)==5) it fails with the following error:

```
raise BulkWriteError(full_result)
pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred
```

What am I missing?

Added based on comment:

ecpDocSorted example:

```
{'address1': 'SOME ADDRESS', 'city': 'Arecibo', 'country': 'US', 'languages': 'English', 'name': 'SOME NAME', 'phone': '123-123-1234', 'postalcode': '00612'}
```

Comment: Could you post the data used for the operation and Just a suggestion you can also use `db.Collection.bulk_write([<an array of insert requests>],upsert=false);` more about [bulk_write](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html)

Comment: Added an example

Comment: I have copied your data in a list, and create 2 similar docs, then run `my_collection.insert_many(list_of_dicts)` and it worked just fine. Maybe the error is elsewhere?

Comment: Thank you Kostas - after your comment I got suspicious that the sorting of the dict prior to appending to bulk and flushing was creating the issue. I have expanded the code snippet to show what is happening before.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with ecpDocSorted.

When using

```
bulk.append(ecpDoc)
```

instead of

```
bulk.append(ecpDocSorted)
```

it just works fine.